# How to use mongoose to update user profile info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

On the client side the user can update their profile through a form where the data is sent via axios to the nodejs express backend. I want to use mongoose to update the user info. Here is what I have tried:

```
userRouter.post('/update/:username', (req, res) => {
  const update = {age: req.body.age, height: req.body.height, weight: req.body.weight, gender: req.body.gender}
  const filter = {username: req.params.username}
  User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing in the database is updating, and the console says the POST request failed.

Comment: Try `User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {...})`

Comment: ah that worked! Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: You can read about it here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing

Answer (score 1):

`findOneAndUpdate` method on `User` returns promise and another flavor where it accepts callback. You did not pass any which caused this error. You can try callback approach or one below written.

```
userRouter.post('/update/:username', async (req, res) => {
    const update = {age: req.body.age, height: req.body.height, weight: req.body.weight, gender: req.body.gender}
    const filter = {username: req.params.username}
    const updatedDocument = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true });

    return res.status(200).send(updatedDocument);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In REST API specification when updating some resources on the server, you have to use the `PATCH` or `PUT` method for the request.

You using the `POST` method.

Here you can do this way

First, get a username and search in the database using filter property.
Now get `req.body` and apply updated data

```
app.patch('/update/:username', (req, res) => {
  //You can pass req.body directly or you can separate object
  const { age, height, weight, gender } = req.body;
  const { username } = req.params;
  const filter = { username : username }

  const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, req.body, { new: true }).catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).send(error);
  });

  return res.status(200).json({
    message : "Updated user",
    data: updatedUser
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me , first create Schema then Import it in your file.

```js
import RegisterSchemaModel from '../schema/RegisterSchema.js';

router.post("/api/admin/epadmin",(req, res) => {
  const uData = {
    "name": req.body.name,
    "lname": req.body.lname,
    "mobile": req.body.mobile,
    "address":req.body.adddress,
    "city":req.body.city,
    "gender":req.body.gender
  }; // Data to be Updated 

  const cData = { "email": req.body.email }; // Conditional Data or Unqiue Key to fetch

  const updatedUser = RegisterSchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate(cData, uData,{new:true}).then((result) => {
    return res.send(result)
  }).catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).send(error);
  });

  return res.status(200).json({
    message : "Updated user",
    data: updatedUser
  });
});
```